# Confusion with dimensions of functions and distributions in functional integration

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, dimensional-analysis

In the $1+3$ spacetime with $c=\frac{h}{2\pi}=1$, the Dirac delta function is of mass dimension $4$. Also, various functions may have various mass dimensions and we can change their dimensions simply by differentiation.

Then, how do we keep the dimension consistent for a functional integration on function spaces? For example, a theorem of Minlos says that for an appropriate generating functional $S$ on the space of test functions, there exists a measure $d\mu$ on its dual space such that
\begin{equation}
S[f]=\int e^{i\phi(f)}d\mu(\phi)
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is any linear continuous functional on the test functions.

Here, $\phi$ can be a delta function or its derivatives as well. Then, $\phi(f)$ can always have a dimension. How can we then even make sense of $e^{i\phi(f)}$?

In mathematics, we did not care about dimensions, but in order to deal with physical quantities, we should consider them. So I am extremely confused.

Could anyone please provide an explanation?

Comment: You must have misunderstood something somewhere, $\phi(f)$ cannot have dimensions as it's in an exponential. I believe $f$ is the dimensional quantity here.

Comment: However, $\phi$ can be a delta function, which yields $\phi(f)=f(0)$. Then, $\phi(f)$ can have a dimension. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Only thing I can think of if it's used in a physical context it will come with some form of normalization then, so as to respect the massless nature of the exponential.